# Tensorflow session run time increasing over time

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm running image recognition (session.run) using TF. I'm looping folder of images and recognize them sequentially, one by one. I encountered strange phenomenon, after ~20-500 images (depend on the machine) the running time of each session.run is increasing . After few hundreds of images, the duration time is almost 100 time slower. Just to clearly, I'm creating the session at the constructor and use it at another function. See the class code below, I create an instance of it and use the recognize function in loop, per image.

Does someone encountered this also, any solutions?

```
def __init__(self, verboseSingleRec=True, verboseSummary=True, modelFile='model.pb', labelFile='labels.txt',
             height=299, width=299, mean=0, std=255,
             input_layer='Mul', output_layer='final_result'):

    self.model_file = modelFile
    self.label_file = labelFile

    self.verbose = False

    # Load Graph
    graph = tf.Graph()
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

    with open(model_file, "rb") as f:
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    with graph.as_default():
        self.graph  = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

    # Load Labels
    label = []          
    proto_as_ascii_lines = tf.gfile.GFile(label_file).readlines()
    for l in proto_as_ascii_lines:
        label.append(l.rstrip())
    self.labels = label

    # Init session
    self.tfSession = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)

def recognize(self, image):
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    input_height=299,
    input_width=299,
    input_mean=0,
    input_std=255

    with tf.Graph().as_default():

        # Get Tensor from image path

        input_name = "file_reader"
        output_name = "normalized"
        file_reader = tf.read_file(image, input_name)
        image_reader = tf.image.decode_png(file_reader, channels=3, name='png_reader')
        float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
        dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0);
        resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, input_width])
        normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])
        sess = tf.Session()
        session_result_1 = sess.run(normalized)

        input_name = "import/" + self.input_layer
        output_name = "import/" + self.output_layer
        input_operation = self.graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
        output_operation = self.graph.get_operation_by_name(output_name);

        sess = self.tfSession
        session_result_2 = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                           {input_operation.outputs[0]: session_result_1})
        return session_result_2
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you use tf.Session lavishly?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to an incorrect use of dataflow paradigm and, thus, of TensorFlow computational graph

The idea is that you compute your graph **only once** and then you run nodes of the graph using your session object. Moreover, the graph should be entirely connected.

In your code there are two problems that do not follow this pattern:

1. For each run of recognize, you build an entire new part of the graph and your graph continuously grows, leading to the slowing performance issue you are talking about. One of the common way to build models incapsulated inside objects is to build your model **entirely** inside the constructor and use methods only to return specific nodes.
2. You are splitting your graph into two different components. First you retrieve `session_result_1` and then you provide this as input of another component of your graph. Try to find a way to connect this two parts (everything inside the constructor) so that you can retrieve your result with a single execution of the session.

Comment: Hi,I've met same problem in inception V3 : splitting graph into two different components. how to connect this two parts?

Comment: The inception V3 code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py